# Fire click event on li element on www.trivago.ie page

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, phantomjs, scrape

I'm writing some phantomjs code to scrape the site [www.trivago.ie](http://www.trivago.ie). First thing I have to do is to change the currency of the page. I've tried to do it with javascript or Jquery with no success.

I'm using the Developer console on the browser to test. According to the code I just have to click a li element, actually, on the console shows that the element has click event attached.

[image: HTML code for li element]

I've tried the following and nothing have worked. After clicking events nothing happens:

Jquery click event:

```
$("li#menu_locale").click()
```

Jquery trigger click event:

```
$("li#menu_locale").trigger("click")
```

Javascript creating event:

```
var a = document.getElementById("menu_locale");
var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(e);
```

I've tried also clicking parents elements but doesn't work. It's an external page so I can't change the code.

The idea of clicking the element is to this element be filled with currency options:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="js_toolbar_localization"></div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that Bijomon is correct and the firefox dev tools are lying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try

```
$("li#menu_locale em").trigger("click");
```

This will open the currency options

Comment: Sorry but it just moves the arrow. The idea of clicking the element is to an element be filled with currency options. (as I've edited on my question). Thanks anyway.

Comment: No, it doesn't open them in either PhantomJS or SlimerJS.

Comment: This will show the currency options, as the em is connected with the function to show the currency options.

Comment: @BijomonVarghese It worked for me after triggering mouseover (which is actually the event that fills the currency options). I've edited your answer with it, thanks for guiding me to the solution!